# Make a discount depending on the country in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation, hook-woocommerce

Because it does not work?
I want it to also have the client's IP to geolocate it help me
I already tried many times but I can't get it to work.

```
function obtener_pais_por_ip() {
    // Reemplaza 'TU_CLAVE_DE_API' con tu clave de API de ipstack
    $api_key = 'TU_CLAVE_DE_API';

    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    // Realizar la solicitud a ipstack
    $response = wp_remote_get("http://api.ipstack.com/$user_ip?access_key=$api_key");

    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        return false;
    }

    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    $data = json_decode($body);

    return $data->country_code;
}

function aplicar_descuento_por_pais($price, $product) {
    $user_country = obtener_pais_por_ip();

    // Define los países elegibles para el descuento y el porcentaje del descuento para cada país
    $countries_discount = array(
        'ES' => 10, // 10% de descuento para España (código ISO 'ES')
        'US' => 15, // 15% de descuento para Estados Unidos (código ISO 'US')
        // Agrega más países y sus respectivos porcentajes de descuento según tus necesidades
    );

    if (isset($countries_discount[$user_country])) {
        // Aplicar el descuento si el país del usuario está en la lista de países elegibles
        $discounted_price = $price * (1 - ($countries_discount[$user_country] / 100));
        return $discounted_price;
    }

    // Si el país del usuario no está en la lista de países elegibles, retornar el precio sin descuento
    return $price;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'aplicar_descuento_por_pais', 10, 2);
```

I want to make them have discounts depending on the country

Comment: _"Because it does not work?"_ -> not a good way to ask on Stack Overflow (welcome btw.), also not a good idea to ask multiple programming questions at once. Focus on one problem and create a [mre] for it. You'll have a better start then. You can always [edit] your question, so this is not a big problem, just in case you wonder. And let me know if you've got any questions or feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the [functional WooCommerce geolocation](https://woocommerce.com/document/maxmind-geolocation-integration/) instead *(integrated with [Maxmind GeoLite2 free](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite2-free-geolocation-data#accessing-geolite2-free-geolocation-data) for countries)*. The settings are in Woocommerce > Settings > Integration (and require opening a free account in Maxmind). 
Also, if you like, in General woocommerce settings, you can set the "Default customer location" to "Geolocation".

The code:

```php
// Get the geolocate country code
function get_user_geoip_country_code() {
    // Get an instance of the WC_Geolocation object class
    $geo_obj = new WC_Geolocation();
    // Get user geolocation from user IP
    $geolocation = (object) $geo_obj->geolocate_ip($geo_obj->get_ip_address());

    return $geolocation->country;
}

// Apply a percentage discount on the product prices based on the geolocated country
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'country_based_discount', 10, 2);
function country_based_discount($price, $product) {
    $geoip_country = get_user_geoip_country_code();

    // Set in the array percentage discount by country
    $country_percentage = array(
        'ES' => 10, // 10% for Spain
        'US' => 15, // 15% for USA
        'FR' => 18, // 18% for France
    );
    // Check if the user country has an available percentage discount
    if ( array_key_exists($geoip_country, $country_percentage) && $country_percentage[$geoip_country] > 0 ) {
        return $price * (1 - ($country_percentage[$geoip_country] / 100)); // calculate the discounted price for that country
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [WooCommerce and MaxMind Geolocation Integration](https://woocommerce.com/document/maxmind-geolocation-integration/)

Comment: It didn't work for me, make the price change even if it's not the country, help

Comment: @CesarHidalgo On my test website this works perfectly… In your case, there is something that has not been set correctly or there is something else that is making trouble, like some custom code, a plugin, your theme or your hosting…